# @State variable in onTapGesture not getting updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

with the code below I was expecting when the image in VStack was tapped, it shows another image in the full screen cover but the *imageName* variable does not seem to get set to *jugg* as in the new full screen it has only a gray background

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var imageName = ""
    @State var showFullscreen = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("drow")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.imageName = "jugg"
                    self.showFullscreen = true
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullscreen) {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 380)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the item: form rather than the isPresented: form of fullScreeenCover

Comment: The state is updated, but not re-injected in `fullScreenCover`, because its content is created once. Use variant `fullScreenCover(item: ...` instead.

Comment: @Asperi can you elaborate on the "because its content is created once" part? I don't really get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, use the `.fullScreenCover(item: ..)` version
of the `fullScreenCover`, such as:

```
struct ImageName: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name = ""
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var imageName: ImageName?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("drow").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    imageName = ImageName(name: "drow")
                }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $imageName) { img in
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
                Image(img.name).resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 380)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to only work if you create a separate SwiftUI view and pass in the `imageName` as a `@Binding` variable

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var imageName = ""
    @State var showFullscreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("drow")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                    imageName = "jugg"
                    
                    showFullscreen = true
                }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullscreen) {
            CoverView(imageName: $imageName)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct CoverView: View {
    
    @Binding var imageName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 380)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue , i was passing @Binding variable to ChildView and it was always failing on first TapGesture . instead , i created Published variable in viewModel and used it in both Views .